# Working with long list in KSH88

Tags: ksh

I am working with a directory that has names of files that are marked for processing and deletion. What I need to do is get the names of all the files and put them into an array and then go through the array and do the work.  Problem is, is that KSH88 only handles arrays up to 1024 in size and that there can be more file names in the directory!

I just need to be able to get the total current file names in the directory as looping through and doing everything else is easy, the current part of the script is:

```
   #This is getting the result set and attempting to get the total file names as initalNumber.
   integer initialNumber=${#`find $source -path "$source/*" -prune -type f -name "$regex" | sed 's!.*/!!'`[@]}
```

This is giving me a "Bad Substitution Error" currently.  This is my first time working with KSH88 so I am not sure if using the result set as an array is even possible.  Any help would be awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you simply get the number of files without such a complicated approach?  e.g.

```
integer initialNumber=$(ls -l | grep -v ^d | wc -l)
```

Are you using the array for other purposes?  There are better ways for iterating through a list of files.  To iterate through a list of files in the current directory, it seems much easier to do this more directly.

e.g.

```
cd $dirname;
for filename in ABC*DEF??.gz; do
    # some action here...
done
```

Comment: My coworker actually came up with a solution the other day, we just did away with using an array at all and did the looping through as each file name was found in the search.  So very similar to your proposed fix.  Thanks!